Scene Reconstruction using ARKit and Metal Swift
I am currently building an iOS app that uses LiDAR to scan outside areas such as rock terrains or caverns. Using ARKit, I've set up the scanner to record ARAnchors and photos, but I'm stuck on texturing the Anchors with real-world material. I am using MetalKit to texture the objects.
Here is where the anchors are added and capture the current image.
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let cameraImage = captureCamera() else { return }
        
        anchors.forEach { anchor in
            if anchor is ARMeshAnchor {
                self.imagesWithAnchor[anchor.identifier] = cameraImage
            }
        }
    }

I am using MDLAsset to render the 3d object
    func generateAsset() -> MDLAsset {
        guard let frame = session.currentFrame else {
            fatalError("Couldn't get the current ARFrame")
        }
        
        // Fetch the default MTLDevice to initialize a MetalKit buffer allocator with
        guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
            fatalError("Failed to get the system's default Metal device!")
        }
        
        // Using the Model I/O framework to export the scan, so we're initialising an MDLAsset object,
        // which we can export to a file later, with a buffer allocator
        let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)
        let asset = MDLAsset(bufferAllocator: allocator)
        
        
        let meshAnchors = frame.anchors.compactMap({ $0 as? ARMeshAnchor })
        
        for anchor in meshAnchors {
            let anchorId = anchor.identifier
            guard let image = imagesAndAnchor[anchorId] else { fatalError("error no image") }
            let mesh = anchor.geometry.toMDLMesh(device: device, transform: anchor.transform, image: image)
            asset.add(mesh)
        }
        
        return asset
    }

    func toMDLMesh(device: MTLDevice, transform: simd_float4x4, image: UIImage ) -> MDLMesh {
        
        let allocator = MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device)
        
        let vertexFormat = MTKModelIOVertexFormatFromMetal(vertices.format)
        
        
        let vertexDescriptor = MDLVertexDescriptor()
        
        vertexDescriptor.attributes[0] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition,
                                                            format: vertexFormat,
                                                            offset: 0,
                                                            bufferIndex: 0)
        
        // Texture coordinate attribute (if needed)
        vertexDescriptor.attributes[1] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeTextureCoordinate,
                                                            format: vertexFormat,
                                                            offset: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3,
                                                            bufferIndex: 0)
        
        vertexDescriptor.layouts[0] = MDLVertexBufferLayout(stride: vertices.stride)

        
        let cgImage = image.cgImage
        let pixelData = cgImage?.dataProvider?.data
        let dataImage: Data = pixelData! as Data
        
        let imageWidth = cgImage?.width
        let imageHeight = cgImage?.height
        
        let bytesPerPixel = 4
        let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth!
        
        let mdlTexture = MDLTexture(data: dataImage, topLeftOrigin: true, name: "jpegTexture", dimensions: vector_int2(Int32(imageWidth!), Int32(imageHeight!)), rowStride: bytesPerRow, channelCount: 4, channelEncoding: .uInt8, isCube: false)
        
        let vertexData = transformedVertexBuffer(transform)
        let textureCoordinateData = generateTextureCoordinates(imageWidth: imageWidth!, imageHeight: imageHeight!, transform: transform)
        
        let data = Data.init(bytes: vertexData, count: vertices.stride * vertices.count)
        
        let vertexDataBytes = vertexData.map { $0.bitPattern }.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
        let textureCoordinateDataBytes = textureCoordinateData.map { $0.bitPattern }.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
        let vertexBuffer = allocator.newBuffer(with: vertexDataBytes + textureCoordinateDataBytes, type: .vertex)
        
        let indexData = Data.init(bytes: faces.buffer.contents(), count: faces.bytesPerIndex * faces.count * faces.indexCountPerPrimitive)
        
        let indexBuffer = allocator.newBuffer(with: indexData, type: .index)
        
        let material = MDLMaterial(name: "jpegTexture", scatteringFunction: MDLPhysicallyPlausibleScatteringFunction())
        
        let textureProperty = MDLMaterialProperty(name: "imageTexture", semantic: .baseColor, textureSampler: nil)
        let sampler = MDLTextureSampler()
        sampler.texture = mdlTexture
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.magFilter = .nearest
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.minFilter = .nearest
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.mipFilter = .nearest
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.rWrapMode = .repeat
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.tWrapMode = .repeat
        sampler.hardwareFilter?.sWrapMode = .repeat
        
        textureProperty.textureSamplerValue = sampler
        material.setProperty(textureProperty)
        
        
        let submesh = MDLSubmesh(indexBuffer: indexBuffer,
                                 indexCount: faces.count * faces.indexCountPerPrimitive,
                                 indexType: .uint32,
                                 geometryType: .triangles,
                                 material: material)
        
        
        let mdlMesh = MDLMesh(vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer,
                              vertexCount: vertices.count,
                              descriptor: vertexDescriptor,
                              submeshes: [submesh])
        
        return mdlMesh
    }

I have read these forums which are similar to this case, but nothing works with the real-world texture.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654431
LiDAR and RealityKit – Capture a Real World Texture for a Scanned Model
Is there any resource outside Swift that can help with mapping real-world texture using ARAnchors and images on Swift?
